# MultiException stack 1 of 2 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration

Tags: java, hibernate, jersey

I am using Jersey and Hibernate. I previously had code is void main that worked getting the Session Factory but this has issues. I have taken sections out of the whole code to simplify.

I know the issue is something to do with the Session Factory will add full stack trace on request, is long.

PS I'm loosely following https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hNBPDHM-3RY

```
        INFO: Server startup in 13357 ms
        Mar 13, 2018 5:06:58 PM org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors logErrors
        WARNING: The following warnings have been detected: WARNING: Unknown HK2 failure detected:
        MultiException stack 1 of 2
        java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration
            at com.web.CurrencyFair.endpoints.service.TradeService.<init>(TradeService.java:28)
        ...
        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration
            at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1335)
            at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1163)
            ... 57 more
        MultiException stack 2 of 2
        java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: create on com.web.CurrencyFair.endpoints.resources.JsonTradeEndpoint
            at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:392)
            at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:471)    
        ...
```

segment of hibernate.cfg.xml. will extra mappings cause issues? i should just need TradeMessage, rite?

```
        <mapping class="com.web.CurrencyFair.endpoints.modules.TradeMessage"/> 
        <mapping class="com.web.CurrencyFair.endpoints.service.TradeService"/>
        <mapping class="com.web.CurrencyFair.endpoints.resources.JsonTradeEndpoint"/>
```

TradeService class

```
        @Path("/")
        @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) // ensure moxy in pom is commented in to use JSON
        @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        public class JsonTradeEndpoint {

            TradeService tradeService = new TradeService();//intit hibernate in constructor

            @GET
            public List<TradeMessage> getTradeMessage() {
            }
            //. . .
        }
```

the line that configures the buildSessionFactory is first line in error.

```
        public class TradeService {

            /*
             * This file provides connection to the DB for the TradeMessage object
             * */

            SessionFactory sessionFactory =  null;
            Session session = null;


            public TradeService() {
                super();
                SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
                this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
                this.session = sessionFactory.openSession(); 
            }

            public List<TradeMessage> getTradeMessages(TradeMessageFilterBean filterBean){
                List<TradeMessage> queryResult = new ArrayList<>();
                //. . .
                return queryResult;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it now by changing a few things, but not 100% sure what one fixed the root cause.

See code changes and CRUD operations

I referenced [(hibernate4) org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13913022/hibernate4-org-hibernate-mappingexception-unknown-entity)

config file

```
        <!-- Names the annotated entity class -->
        <mapping class="com.web.CurrencyFair.endpoints.modules.TradeMessage"/> 
        <!--<mapping class="com.web.CurrencyFair.endpoints.service.TradeService"/>
        <mapping class="com.web.CurrencyFair.endpoints.resources.JsonTradeEndpoint"/>-->
```

Below is the updated Code

```
        public class TradeService {

        Configuration configuration = null;
        //StandardServiceRegistryBuilder ssrb = null;
        SessionFactory sessionFactory =  null;
        Session session = null;

        private void init() {
            configuration = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
            //ssrb = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
            sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory();
            session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        }

        public List<TradeMessage> getTradeMessages(TradeMessageFilterBean filterBean){
            List<TradeMessage> queryResult = new ArrayList<>();

            try {

                if(session == null) this.init();

                TradeMessage trademessage = new TradeMessage(654321);

                session = sessionFactory.openSession();
                session.beginTransaction();

                //C
                session.save(trademessage);
                //R
                TradeMessage newTM = (TradeMessage) session.get(TradeMessage.class, 1);
                System.out.println("TM = : " + newTM.toString());
                //U
                newTM.setId(100);
                session.update(newTM);
                newTM = (TradeMessage) session.get(TradeMessage.class, 1);
                System.out.println("TM = : " + newTM.toString());
                //D
                session.delete(newTM);

                session.getTransaction().commit();
                session.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            } finally {
            }

            return queryResult; 
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that `org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration` is on the classpath and `WebappClassLoaderBase` can see it?

Comment: Yes thank-you. It is located in the resources src folder. Fixed it now, see answer.